# Media playback faster than normal

Tags: release-loki, pantheon, multimedia

There's a strange problem where one of the accounts in my desktop plays media faster than normal speed. At first I thought this was a problem with the Epiphany browser, but then even the music player plays things fast. I recorded the screen to illustrate this:

https://streamable.com/zza2a
https://streamable.com/8ex86

I don't even know where or how to begin troubleshooting this. There are three user accounts in the computer and this happens in only one of them. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Settings -> Sound -> (change the output device)

Comment: This worked. Just that there was no option to change device in the "Sound" option. I remembered that I had manipulated Sound device in Skype settings; I just had to revert it to fix the problem. Thanks a ton! ;)